# Write a recipe in yocto for a python application

Tags: python-3.x, embedded-linux, yocto

I have a simple python application which does:

1. acquire information from a GPS
2. parse information
3. store it in InfluxDB

The package requirements:

```
certifi==2018.4.16
chardet==3.0.4
idna==2.6 
influxdb==5.0.0
pynmea2==1.12.0 
pyserial==3.4
python-dateutil==2.7.3
pytz==2018.4
requests==2.18.4
six==1.11.0
urllib3==1.22
```

The above is generated by using:

`pip3 install pynmea2 pyserial influxdb`

In the `OpenEmbedded Layers Index` I have already found `pyserial` package for **Python3**. Which implies on the board I just might need to do `pip3 install pynmea2 influxdb`.

How do you go ahead writing my application's recipe with all the above mentioned pip dependencies in mind?

There aren't any tutorials I have found for writing recipes for python applications. (On the contrary `Node` applications do have some guidance on the [wiki page for yocto](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks/NPM).

Upon checking some recipes in `meta-python` layer I found some `.inc` files but not sure how to go about it

Comment: In _bitbake_ [_.inc_](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#include-directive) files are used to support shared functionality between recipes - [example](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-python/recipes-devtools/python/python-pyserial.inc).

Comment: When meet .inc file such as in http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-python/recipes-devtools/python/python3-pyserial_3.4.bb?h=master, you could just think that expand the .inc file in the .bb file. And for the requirements you list, put them in RDEPENDS_${PN} in .bb/.inc file. See http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-python/recipes-devtools/python/python-pyserial.inc#n33

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Creating Recipes for non-available python apps

Since `influxdb-python` and `pynmea2` are not available as standard python recipes, I began by creating recipes for them using `devtool`.

#### Steps

1. use `devtool` to add the `influxdb-python`

   `devtool add influxdb-python  https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python/archive/v5.2.0.tar.gz`
2. use `devtool` to add the `pynmea2`

   `devtool add pynmea2 https://github.com/Knio/pynmea2/archive/1.7.1.tar.gz`

The above mentioned steps creates a folder `workspace` in your `$BUILD_DIR` and created auto-generated recipes for the repos.

3. Edit the recipes

   `devtool edit-recipe influxdb-python`
4. add or check `DEPEND_${PN}` and `RDEPENDS_${PN}` to your recipes accordingly. I added all the `requirements.txt` for `influxdb-python` to `RDEPENDS_${PN}` viz.

   `RDEPEND_${PN} += "${PYTHON_PN}-modules ${PYTHON_PN}-requests  ${PYTHON_PN}-dateutil ${PYTHON_PN}-pytz ${PYTHON_PN}-six"`

   **NOTE**: I have not added `pandas` or `numpy` as they aren't relevant for my application.
5. I added `DEPENDS_${PN} = "${PYTHON_PN}-modules` also.

> **NOTE**: Perform the same for `pynmea2` but since it does not have any `requirements.txt` I added `RDEPENDS_${PN} = "${PYTHON_PN}-modules"` so all major things are available on the target.

#### Recipe Structure

[GitHub Gist for Recipes](https://gist.github.com/shantanoo-desai/fc00836d399f8592a30efe1ec9c56213)

I followed the `meta-python` folder's structure where each of the recipes consists of :

- `recipe.inc`
- `recipe_version_number.bb`

In the `influxdb_python.inc` keep all the stuff generated from `devtool` viz.

```
# Recipe created by recipetool
# This is the basis of a recipe and may need further editing in order to be fully functional.
# (Feel free to remove these comments when editing.)
#
# WARNING: the following LICENSE and LIC_FILES_CHKSUM values are best guesses - it is
# your responsibility to verify that the values are complete and correct.
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=046523829184aac3703a4c60c0ae2104"

HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb-python"
SUMMARY = "InfluxDB client"

SRC_URI = "https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python/archive/v${PV}.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "105d88695151e241523b31dd1375096e"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "620de85bcca5207b06ec1565884b6d10b4be01d579a78e08b1e922f453fdac05"

DEPENDS_${PN} = "${PYTHON_PN}-modules"
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "${PYTHON_PN}-modules ${PYTHON_PN}-requests ${PYTHON_PN}-dateutil ${PYTHON_PN}-pytz ${PYTHON_PN}-six"
```

In the `influxdb_python_5.2.0.bb` I added the following lines:

```
inherit setuptools3 pypi                              
require influxdb-python.inc
```

> **NOTE**: I added `setuptools3` since I want my app to be run on `python3.5`. For python2.7 use `setuptools`.

Similarly, I did the same for `pynmea2.inc`:

```
# Recipe created by recipetool
# This is the basis of a recipe and may need further editing in order to be fully functional.
# (Feel free to remove these comments when editing.)
#
# WARNING: the following LICENSE and LIC_FILES_CHKSUM values are best guesses - it is
# your responsibility to verify that the values are complete and correct.
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=bb5e173bc54080cb25079199959ba6b6"

HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/Knio/pynmea2"
SUMMARY = "Python library for the NMEA 0183 protcol"

SRC_URI = "https://github.com/Knio/pynmea2/archive/${PV}.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "a90baf61f4e676bef76099e4bd7c0581"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "8f8f68623bd2d5dab7f04a9c31813a3f4aa15467db0373cbce6b9b0ae44ca48e"

#DEPENDS_${PN} = "${PYTHON_PN}-datetime ${PYTHON_PN}-threading ${PYTHON_PN}-io"
DEPENDS_${PN} = "${PYTHON_PN}-modules"
# WARNING: the following rdepends are determined through basic analysis of the
# python sources, and might not be 100% accurate.
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "${PYTHON_PN}-modules"
```

For `pynmea2_1.7.1.bb`:

```
inherit setuptools3 pypi
require pynmea2.inc
```

#### Baking the recipes

You could test them with
`bitbake -k influxdb-python` and `bitbake -k pynmea2`
or with
`devtool build influxdb-python` and `devtool build pynmea2`

If you have no errors then you can deploy it on target using:

```
devtool deploy-target influxdb-python user@machineIP:dest_folder
```

#### Checks

You can check by firing the python shell

```
# python3 

 >> import influxdb-python
 >> import pyserial
```

if the import is throws no missing modules error then it is success!!

#### Final steps

- You can undeploy the modules: `devtool undeploy-target recipe_name [address of target]`
- send the recipes to you custom meta layer `devtool finish recipe_name ../meta-custom`

> **NOTE**: If you are using `krogoth` or lower the you will have to move your recipes to you meta layer manually

- Now include these recipes in your `conf/local.conf` with `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " influxdb-python pynmea2"`  and `bitbake -k your-image-name`

### Custom Application

> Not tested yet.

But I think I will simple add my app like mentioned in [YoctoCookBook Repository for `hello-world`](https://github.com/yoctocookbook/meta-custom/tree/master/recipes-python/python-helloworld) with my `meta` layer.

## NUGGETS

- `${PYTHON_PN}-modules` is a saviour really. I tried manually added runtime deps and everytime i deployed it on the board there were always some dependencies missing. But adding the `modules` solved all the missing deps issue in an instance.
- I am not sure when to use `DEPENDS_${PN}` but I assume most python applications depend on the basic `python-modules` hence I added them.
- **NOT A YOCTO EXPERT** but this is just my finding in the last 2 weeks. There is a lack of proper examples for Python in Yocto. hope this helps someone.