# Bitbake Recipe for a python3 repository that provides a CLI as a binary

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, yocto, bitbake

I have some simple python3 scripts that I packaged in such a way that upon `pip install .` within the repository one can use the scripts within the `bin` folder as a CLI e.g.

```
 $ gpsinflux # execute the script as cli
```

#### source

[gpsinflux](https://github.com/iotfablab/gpsinflux) repository.

#### Workflow

1. I used `devtool add gpsinflux url_of_repo`
2. I already managed to add `influxdb-python` as a recipe based on my findings in my [previous SE Query regarding python application on yocto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50436413/write-a-recipe-in-yocto-for-a-python-application)
3. Edit the recipe to add `RDEPENDS_PN`

However do I need to mention within the recipe that I want the script in the `bin` folder from my repository to be installed in say, `/usr/bin` folder or will the recipe do that automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Checked on Target Hardware

One does not require to perform `do_install()` at all. If the `setup.py` does have `packages=[bin/script1]` then upon sucessfully baking the recipe and adding the recipe to you Root Filesystem will automatically provide your `script1` in `/usr/bin/` folder.

#### Cross Reference

I looked into `python-awscli` example in [meta-iot-cloud](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/meta-iot-cloud/blob/master/recipes-aws/python/python-awscli_1.16.57.bb) and there it is no mention of `do_install()`

in the same repository if one needs to port python2.7 to python3 one can use `sed` to change the shebang of the `bin/script1` using `do_install_append()`